# How to get OS information from minidump crash?

Tags: visual-studio, windbg, crash-dumps

I am trying to debug a minidump crash dump. How can I get to know the OS so that I may download related Microsoft Symbols?

I am using Visual studio and windbg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertarget` will tell you the target machine of the minidump.

Answer (score 3):

The dump contains enough information so that the symbol server client will load download and use the symbols that match the executable and dlls.

I.e. define environment variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` to something like:

```
symsrv*symsrv.dll*h:\Symbols*http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

where `h:\symbols` is a writeable folder. The debugging tools will do the rest.

Note:

- You need to do it this way because patches, including service packs, also change the version of the symbols.
- The first download location is used for .NET with source server, if not working with .NET that can be removed.

Comment: +1. Use of Symbol Servers is one of the most productive things you can do if you're involved in analysing crash dumps.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen that syntax for the MS symbol server before, I usually just do:

.symfix h:\symbols 
.reload

From within the debugging session. It automatically sets your symbol search path to point to the symbol server so you don't have to worry about remembering the path.

-scott